# I need to get the field of custom post type on advance custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $series = get_field('series'); ?>

<?php foreach($series as $series):?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($series->ID, 'thumbnail');?> ">
         <h3><?php echo $series->post_title;?></h3>
          
         <!-- <?php the_field('series_details');?> This is the field that i want to pull out -->

       </a>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

i need to get the field of acf on my custom post type.

Comment: Can you try the_field( 'series_details', $series->ID ); ?

Comment: not working.. please help me

Comment: I'll try. Send a screenshot of the fields please, so I understand how you have them set up. Also can you do add, after the_field( 'series_details', $series->ID ); some quick log of what $series->ID is outputting ?

Comment: Hello Tami! THANK YOU Its working now thank you for helping me!!!

Comment: I'll post the fix as an answer, and if you accept it, you help others with the same problem find it in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting field values outside the loop, you need to pass the id of the current object (Post, Term, User) as the second parameter to the functions get_the_field or the_field. Like so:

```
<?php $series = get_field('series'); ?>

<?php foreach($series as $series): ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($series->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?> ">
         <h3><?php echo $series->post_title;?></h3>
          
         <?php the_field('series_details', $series->ID); ?> <!--  This is the field that i want to pull out -->

       </a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

ACF Documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

The same applies if you are using WordPress' inbuilt get_post_meta or get_user_meta, only you pass the id as the first parameter

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/